# VS2015 template specialization errors

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2015

The following code produces two compiler errors in vs2015:

C2995: `void TestSpecialization<T>::f(void)`: function template has already been defined

C3860: template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list.

```
template <typename T>

class TestSpecialization
{
public:
    void f() {}
};

template <typename T>
void TestSpecialization<T*>::f() // C3860, C2995
{}
```

WRONG ORDER?!  This initially seemed nearly reasonable... the template originally had 3 parameters (in the correct order, btw).  But now it has a single parameter, how in the name of all that links do you manage to get that in the wrong order?!

**Thoughts**

Methinks the type listed in the error for 2995 is a clue, it lists the original type without the `T*`.

Just to muddy the waters, `std::is_pointer` compiles just fine.

It's entirely possible that we're using some strange compatibility flag on the compiler.

No, I can't use `if constexpr` instead.  Ah... to dream.

Comment: is that specialization legal ? checking with online compilers none of the c++ version (03,11,14) seem to work

Comment: Can you pop open the "Output Window" which has the full text of the error messages? The "Error Window" only has the one line summaries that you posted.

Comment: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ issues the same errors, shockingly.  The good news is this rules out the "strange compatibility flag" issue.

Comment: The problem is not Visual Studio. This shouldn't compile anywhere.

Comment: That's were I was taking this from.  The C2995 had some additional info "note: see declaration of `TestSpecialization<T>::f`

Comment: @ACB this is partial specialization, not explicit.

Comment: @AndyG could you be more specific?

Comment: @MarkStorer: Partial specialization only applies to _classes_. You cannot partially specialize a method.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's it!  Thank you.

Comment: Oh.  The WHOLE class.  That's less good.  All those helper classes make much more sense now.